# Linux - move ssd drive from /dev/sdb to /dev/sda and boot linux installed when the drive was mapped /dev/sdb

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, ssd, slackware

I have a dual boot notebook with windows 7 installed in /dev/hda1 and slackware linux in /dev/sdb1.
Now I want to move the ssd disk to /dev/sda1, replacing hda. Next I want to install the former hda1 disk as /dev/hdb1 and format it).
My question is: is there a way to boot the linux partition now in /dev/sda1, installed when the drive was mapped as /dev/sdb1?

Answer (score 0):

After creating partitions and copying them from source disk to target disk, you would only need to run `update-grub2` (and/or `grub-install`) and update `/etc/fstab` file. Then the systems should boot up.

Problematic would be if Windows has few partitions (boot, system with Windows folder).

But always it is better for SSD drive systems when moving from HDD drives to install systems from scratch. As installation can check if the drive is HDD or SSD and the apply some configurations depending on the drive type.